# set array value to pandas dataframe cell in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm looking for assigning an array type value( pandas index array) to a pandas dataframe cell in python 3.

```
result["indices"] = np.nan
for i in result.index:
    result.loc[i, "indices"] = pd.Index(masks[i])
```

I've tried also the code blow in place of the assignment above in the for block

```
    result.set_value(i, "indices", pd.Index(masks[i])
```

Both the two assignments above cause ValueError.
The idea is to add a new column to store an array of index.
Is there any solution? 
Or should I convert array to an object or string type?
Thanks

a solution not very elegent is to convert it to a dict

```
result>set_value( i, "indices", {"value" : pd.Index(masks[i])} )
```

Comment: Are you basically trying to set an `object` value to an element of a non-`object` column?

Comment: Probably a better start would be, what are the dtypes of your columns?

Comment: Hi, the column is new created, and the objective is to assign an array of indexes (it could be a list or ndarray as well) to this new column. @MadPhysicist